# vim commands in snipmate snippet

Tags: python, vim, snipmate

I am using snipmate plugin with vim. How can I write any commands in snipmate snippet that I would be able to write to .vimrc? Like `<ESC>`, `<leader>`, `<cr>` and so on...

I want to be able to write a snippet that imports python debugger, sets trace and then returns to normal mode. I struggle with returning to normal mode. I have no idea how to code it using snipmate.

Basically I would want something like this, however this won't work properly:

```
snippet pdb
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()<ESC>
```

This will just add `'<ESC>'` at the end, but I want to return to normal mode instead. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just write a macro? http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

snipMate *snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. It appears that you don't need all this advanced functionality here, so instead you would be better served with a plain insert-mode abbreviation, where you can indeed use the Vim key-notation:

```
:ia pdb import pdb; pdb.set_trace()<ESC>
```

With snipMate itself, leaving insert mode is not possible.